# Show popup based on state

Tags: semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I use a Popup to show an error message on an input if validation fails.

```
<Popup
    trigger={InputComponent}
    open={state.error}
    content={errorMessage}
/>
```

This works fine, but the annoying part is that when I focus the element an empty popup appears. I can't disable this behaviour for as far as I know.
I've tried adding `on={null}` and `on="none"`, but all this does not work.

Any ideas? It would be nice to disable triggering the popup, but to allow it to be visible on state value only.

Comment: Maybe wrap it in a conditional statement? `{ state.error && <Popup trigger={InputComponent} open={state.error} content={errorMessage} />}`

Comment: This does not work, a Popup should be rendered before showing, otherwise it does not know where to place the popup (I tried this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage is very similar to one of the cases mentioned in the docs: https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/popup#popup-example-controlled

Make sure `state.error` returns bool type and not string bool and finally, check you are able to close it after the popup opens using `onOpen` handler as an added measure to make sure you are able to atleast control the component's state.

Finally, as a hack, you can add a `{{display: "none"}}` through Popup's style prop when `this.state.error === true`

**An example usage from SUI docs of a Popup that automatically after 2.5 seconds:**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button, Grid, Header, Popup } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const timeoutLength = 2500

class PopupExampleControlled extends React.Component {
  state = { isOpen: false }

  handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: true })

    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ isOpen: false })
    }, timeoutLength)
  }

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: false })
    clearTimeout(this.timeout)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Grid>
        <Grid.Column width={8}>
          <Popup
            trigger={<Button content='Open controlled popup' />}
            content={`This message will self-destruct in ${timeoutLength / 1000} seconds!`}
            on='click'
            open={this.state.isOpen}
            onClose={this.handleClose}
            onOpen={this.handleOpen}
            position='top right'
          />
        </Grid.Column>
        <Grid.Column width={8}>
          <Header>State</Header>
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state, null, 2)}</pre>
        </Grid.Column>
      </Grid>
    )
  }
}

export default PopupExampleControlled
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone facing the same issue, the easiest fix would be to add a custom popup style to your popup tag and define opacity with the state as below.

```
const style = {
    opacity: this.state.isOpen ? "1" : "0"
}


<Popup style={style} trigger={<Button icon='add' />} content='Add users to your feed'/>
```